# Problem with differentiating an identity regarding one-family of diffeomorphisms

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives, partial-derivative

[image]

I really dont see how the differentiation with respect to t has been done. Before and after the third equation I am ok.

Hopefully this is enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good you're ok after that equation, because I have no idea who $q$ is!

This sort of calculation is best understood by applying the chain rule to a composition. Set
$$F(s,t) = f_s\circ\Phi_t$$
and consider $F\circ g$, where $g(t) = (t,t)$. Now you'll agree that the usual chain rule tells us that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial s} &= \frac{\partial f_s}{\partial s}\circ\Phi_t, \text{ and} \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} &= (Df_s\circ\Phi_t)\big(\frac{\partial\Phi_t}{\partial t}\big).
\end{align*}
Now, putting this together, we have 
$$\dfrac d{dt}F(t,t) = \big(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial s}+\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}\big)\Big|_{s=t}= \frac{\partial f_t}{\partial s}\circ\Phi_t + (Df_t\circ\Phi_t)\big(\frac{\partial\Phi_t}{\partial t}\big),$$
which is your desired equation.

Comment: Could you show how this works for the third equation. Additionally, it may be worth nothing, that in my notes I have $f \circ \Phi_t = f_t$ and I am now wondering whether this is a typo. This comes from a question which guides through a proof of Morse's Lemma.

Comment: I added the final line of computation. Well, what you've posted is consistent with your original $f_t\circ \Phi_t = f$. Of course, we can rewrite this as $f_t = f\circ \Phi_{-t}$. :)